# ffmpeg warning: "unknown side data type"

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

When trying to run a video conversion or a desktop recording with ffmpeg I'm getting this warning message in yellow color: `unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)`. Using ffmpeg in Arch Linux x86_64 compiled from the git repository (git version).

Output of a simple video conversion:

```
$ ffmpeg -i video1.avi video2.mp4
ffmpeg version N-77722-g3ec5d8f Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg  developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg-full-git --extra-cflags='-I/usr/include/nvidia-sdk -I/opt/x265-hg/include' --extra-ldflags='-L/opt/x265-hg/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/x265-hg/lib' --cpu=native --enable-rpath --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-gray --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaacplus --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libquvi --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsmbclient --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libutvideo --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxcb --enable-libxcb-shm --enable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-libxcb-shape --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-decklink --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 23.100 /  6. 23.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'video1.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.31.0
  Duration: 00:04:09.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 633 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 892x668 [SAR 1:1 DAR 223:167], 497 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 5 tbn, 5 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.21.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 892x668 [SAR 1:1 DAR 223:167], q=-1--1, 5 fps, 10240 tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1247 fps=139 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5433kB time=00:04:09.24 bitrate= 178.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=27.8x    
video:1464kB audio:3891kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.446609%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] frame I:6     Avg QP: 9.37  size: 89238
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] frame P:338   Avg QP:16.29  size:  2085
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] frame B:903   Avg QP:20.75  size:   286
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] consecutive B-frames:  3.3%  0.0%  1.4% 95.3%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] mb I  I16..4: 56.4%  4.2% 39.4%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] mb P  I16..4:  1.1%  0.3%  0.4%  P16..4:  3.1%  0.4%  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:94.4%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.9%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:96.4%  L0:56.6% L1:43.1% BI: 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] 8x8 transform intra:17.0% inter:56.4%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 17.8% 25.8% 20.4% inter: 0.3% 0.7% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 38% 60%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  7% 22% 69%  1%  0%  0%  0%  0%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 27% 18%  4%  5%  3%  3%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 39% 14%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] ref P L0: 67.1%  4.6% 17.9% 10.4%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] ref B L0: 64.2% 32.5%  3.2%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] ref B L1: 93.0%  7.0%
[libx264 @ 0x27e77e0] kb/s:48.07
[aac @ 0x27e8700] Qavg: 633.592
```

Even in a more complete command the same warning still persists. For example, when trying to record the desktop:

```
$ ffmpeg -f pulse -thread_queue_size 512 -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -i default -f x11grab -thread_queue_size 512 -r 60 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0+224,235 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 -r 60 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv444p -threads 0 screencast.mkv                          
ffmpeg version N-77722-g3ec5d8f Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg-full-git --extra-cflags='-I/usr/include/nvidia-sdk -I/opt/x265-hg/include' --extra-ldflags='-L/opt/x265-hg/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/x265-hg/lib' --cpu=native --enable-rpath --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-gray --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaacplus --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libquvi --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsmbclient --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libutvideo --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxcb --enable-libxcb-shm --enable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-libxcb-shape --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-decklink --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 23.100 /  6. 23.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, pulse, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1452122996.525850, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Input #1, x11grab, from ':0.0+224,235':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1452122997.816378, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 60 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.2, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=0 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
Output #0, matroska, to 'screencast.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.21.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv444p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 pcm_s16le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  748 fps= 56 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10237kB time=00:00:12.58 bitrate=6662.7kbits/s speed=0.948x    
video:7871kB audio:2360kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.063400%
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] frame I:3     Avg QP: 0.00  size:304901
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] frame P:745   Avg QP: 0.00  size:  9590
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] mb P  I16..4: 46.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  1.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:52.8%
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] coded y,u,v intra: 1.1% 0.2% 0.2% inter: 1.8% 0.3% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 99%  1%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x283ed40] kb/s:5171.57
```

It does not seem to be a specific H.264 warning because it also shows when using VP9 video codec.

What this warning mean and what I need to do to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore it. That message has been regularly popping up since mid-December builds for me. But my commands with a diverse set of inputs process normally as before.

Interestingly, that [code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/b4679ecdbd80ae050094733f137ccd7ebf1316ab?diff=split) was added in Feb 2014, but haven't seen those messages till recently.